# A man unties you in a dank, grotty room. You have 5 choices

Tags: logical-deduction

A man unties you in a dank, grody room. He pulls out a chair and asks you some personal questions. He then offers you a choice:

Stay in this room for the rest of your life, or take a chance on your life to leave.
He also releases a cage full of arthropods.
You take the later choice.

He tells you:

> You have some choices. You can go into 1 of 5 rooms. Each of them will have a sign, and you get to choose which one will NOT kill you.

You walk into the hallway and see:

> DOOR 1: Could door 5 be lie? You might as well try?

> DOOR 2: Numbers three and five might keep you safe, but door 1 will lead to death.

> DOOR 3: Door 1 is quite lie, certainly to bring demise.

> DOOR 4: Do you believe that three could say such things, such lies will not keep you safe.

> DOOR 5:That is wrong door four, a number in it's prime will serve just fine.

Which door do you choose? Will you live? Will you die?

Comment: Dont be shy! Give it a try!

Comment: [Strafe](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/strafe)?

Comment: I have edited to make it easier to understand for yall

Comment: sorry bout that misspell I be new and a puzzle rookie again tysm for the constructive critism

Comment: You mean an [arthropod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod)?

Comment: I made a few typos: sorry

Comment: While you're at it, with "grody" did you mean "grotty"?

Comment: Thank you! I'm not that good at acurracy on my chromebook! ;)

Comment: here we go, made it a tad bit easier to understand, whilst keeping a hint of confusion.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis "Grody" is local dialect slang in some parts of BrEng - same meaning as grotty.

Comment: I think you meant "latter," not "later"

Comment: Yes, yes I did. We'll call this one the PC for the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Door 5 says to not trust a door in "it's [sic] prime". If we interpret that as saying we shouldn't trust door with primes numbers, then we shouldn't trust Door 5, since 5 is prime. Door 1 seems to endorse Door 5, and Door 3 seems to endorse Door 1, and Door 2 seems to endorse Door 3, so that leaves Door 4.

But that requires a lot of inference leaps of logic. I think this puzzle is rather poor, as there isn't really a basis in the clues themselves to come to a conclusion; only by assuming that a solution is *intended*, and that the solution given above is the closest to a logically supported one, can we infer that this is the intended solution.

Comment: your answer is correct.

Comment: Door 5 presents us with a [liar paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox) so I'm not convinced you can then make valid deductions at all.

Comment: So we're supposed to choose the door which neither deprecates itself nor suggests that a different door is the one? How are we supposed to be able to determine that from the puzzle?

Comment: Cite door 5. It has to do with math. I will edit it to make it a tad less confusing.

Comment: I edited it to make it slightly easier to read, and understand.

Answer (score 0):

I propose that the answer is

> door 5.

This is simply because

> door 1 says that "door 5 holds a key," implying that that's the door that will lead to freedom.

After all, we may assume that

> all of the doors are truthful, since the things they say don't contradict each other or anything else we know.

Comment: Not quite, try using what door five says instead.